# How do I disable object reference creation in the Newtonsoft JSON serializer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I switched my ASP.NET MVC application to use the Newtonsoft JsonSerializer to do our JSON serialization, as such:

```
var writer = new JsonTextWriter(HttpContext.Response.Output) { Formatting = Formatting };
var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create();
serializer.Serialize(writer, myData);
```

This generates some JSON that has $id and $ref properties and then removes duplicate objects from the JSON.  I know it's a feature that is great, but the clients that read this JSON cannot support interpreting these references and expect full objects to be there.  I've tried setting the `PreserveReferencesHandling` property on the `JsonSerializerSettings` to every possible value and it doesn't seem to make any difference.

How can I disable the creation of the $id and $ref properties and get the Newtonsoft serializer to write out the whole object graph?

**EDIT**: here is a sample C# class, the JSON I expect, and the JSON created by the Newtonsoft serializer:

```
public class Product
{
    public Image MainImage { get; set; }

    public List<Image> AllImages { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

JSON I expect:

```
{
    MainImage: { Id: 1, Url: 'http://contoso.com/product.png' },
    AllImages: [{ Id: 1, Url: 'http://contoso.com/product.png' },{ Id: 2, Url: 'http://contoso.com/product2.png' }]
}
```

JSON created by the Newtonsoft serializer (note the added $id parameter in MainImage and the referenced object being completely replaced by a $ref parameter):

```
{
    MainImage: { $id: 1, Id: 1, Url: 'http://contoso.com/product.png' },
    AllImages: [{ $ref: 1 },{ Id: 2, Url: 'http://contoso.com/product2.png' }]
}
```

I understand that the Newtonsoft version is better (it's DRYer) but the client that reads this JSON output does not understand what $ref means.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some sample data that is representative of what you are trying to serialize, as well as the desired JSON output.

Comment: @BrianRogers I've edited to include sample code and data.

Comment: Which Newtonsoft version are you using? Because in an empty project with the version 5.0.6 I get your expected result without the $id and $ref...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I see from your comments that your classes are actually decorated with `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]`, so that explains why you are seeing the reference information getting added to your JSON.  From the [JSON.Net documentation on Serialization Attributes](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/SerializationAttributes.htm):

> As well as using the built-in Json.NET attributes, Json.NET also looks for the [SerializableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcfsa90a) (if IgnoreSerializableAttribute on DefaultContractResolver is set to false) [DataContractAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585243), [DataMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574795) and [NonSerializedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z951x24h) ... when determining how JSON is to be serialized and deserialized.

It also says this:

> **Note**
>
> Json.NET attributes take precedence over standard .NET serialization attributes, e.g. if both JsonPropertyAttribute and DataMemberAttribute are present on a property and both customize the name, the name from JsonPropertyAttribute will be used.

So, it seems the solution to your problem is simple: just add `[JsonObject(IsReference = false)]` to your classes like this:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[JsonObject(IsReference = false)]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public Image MainImage { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Image> AllImages { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[JsonObject(IsReference = false)]
public class Image
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow you to keep your WCF attributes in place, but will override the reference behavior when it is time to serialize to JSON.

Comment: So, I believe I figured it out. In a standalone project, this code works just as you describe.  However, the objects that I'm using are decorated with a `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` attribute because they're also used in a WCF service layer.  I was not expecting the Newtonsoft JSON serializer to actually look at a WCF attribute, but I guess it does, even if `PreserveReferencesHandling` is set to None.  Any idea how to disable that?

Comment: I did the exact same thing as you wrote, i have wcf with `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` and also `[JsonObject(IsReference = false)]` but still uses `$id`

Comment: I pray you long live sir